# Israel-centric map projection

Tags: product-recommendation, eretz-yisrael, geography

Does anyone know how to get a hold of an [azimuthal equidistant projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AzimuthalEquidistantProjection.html) of the globe with Israel/Jerusalem at the center. (See: http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/CartDef/MapDef/mapDef.html#Aspect; Such a map is defined by direction and distance from Israel; Potential halachik uses: [demonstrating halachik davening directions](http://www.myzmanim.com/read/direction.aspx); arguably, calculating techumin.)  The closest I've found is centered in the Gulf Guinea:[image] 
Also relevant: http://mrgris.com/projects/merc-extreme/#396d334d@6.88748,158.21507 though it appears to use 2 poles rather than one. The map I'm looking for should have Israel at the center with every point on the globe represented such that the distance and direction from Israel are accurate (in which case I believe Micronesia becomes the outer border).

Comment: Shouldn't the title be Israel-centric?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://ns6t.net/azimuth/ creates Azimuthal Equidistant Projections for any point.

Set Location as Jerusalem, and Distance as about 20,000.